# About a particular solution of the equation $y''-y=e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

ODE:  $y''-y=e^x$.

I found  that complemantary solution of the ode is
$y_c=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$. No problem.

But, I don' t understand why do we suppose that trial solution is $y_p=Axe^x$ instead of $y_p=Ae^x$ ?

What is the key point for selection of a particular solution of an ODE?

Comment: both is not true, try $$y_p=Ae^x+Bxe^x$$

Comment: If you want to avoid making a guess for a particular solution, try using [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)

Comment: consider a differential that is very close to this:$y'' - y = e^{1.1x}.$ look for a particular solution in the form $k{e^{1.1x} - e^x}.$ see what happens when you make the $0.1$ even smaller.

Comment: The reason that you don't use $y_p=Ae^x$ is because then $y_p''+y_p=0\neq e^x$. More broadly, a particular solution is intended to solve the inhomogeneous problem, so any solution to the homogeneous problem is useless for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always check the complementary solution, $y'' - y = 0$, before identifying a particular solution.

$y'' - y = 0$ has a solution of the form $y = C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x}$. Since the right handside, $e^x$, is a term in the complementary solution you can usually try multiplying the particular solution that you would try, $y_p = Ae^x$, by $x$: try $y_p = Ax e^x$.